# Why did the Salaxalan ghost influence Coleridge to write Kubla Khan?

Tags: dirk-gently

**Major spoilers ahead for *Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency.***

In the first Dirk Gently book, Samuel Taylor Coleridge is possessed by the ghost of the Salaxalan engineer. Under the influence of this ghost, Coleridge writes the poem "Kubla Khan," which in this universe contains a second verse with what is implied to be instructions to fix his ship.

At the end of the book, Dirk interrupts Coleridge and makes him forget this second verse somehow preventing the ghost from repairing the ship.

My question is, why did the ghost need Coleridge to write the poem and why did removing the second verse from history cause the ghost's plan to fail?